# MS word: a macro to turn ON/OFF some proofing settings

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2013

What macro could turn ON/OFF some proofing settings? (Unfortunately macro recording doesn't record the setting change)

I'm looking for a way to turn ON/OFF 2 proofing settings (at the same time):

- check spelling as you type
- mark grammar errors as you type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType & .CheckSpellingAsYouType is what you're looking for.

Example:

```
Sub GrammarSpellingOn()
    Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = True
    Application.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = True
End Sub

Sub GrammarSpellingOff()
    Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = False
    Application.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = False
End Sub
```

To turn ON/OFF using the same macro, with a popup stating the change done:

```
Sub GrammarSpellingOnOff()
    If Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = True Or Application.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = True Then
        Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = False
        Application.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = False
        Call MsgBox("Grammar & Spell Checking turned OFF")
    Else
        Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = True
        Application.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = True
        Call MsgBox("Grammar & Spell Checking turned ON")
    End If
    Application.ScreenRefresh 'refresh to add/remove spellchecker underlines
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I edited your answer to add the rest of the code to tun it ON-OFF with the same macro

Comment: You're welcome! Was thinking of writing it like toggle: "Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = not Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType" but who says you start with both on or off? :)

Comment: the only things that could be improved is that we don't know when it's turn on or off (an alert would be handy!) since it takes some time before updating, or the text need to be edited to removed the underlined parts.

Comment: alright, I didn't see your edit before, so you want it to turn off if any of them is on. Added a msgbox to tell you what happened ;)

Comment: great thanks again! Just a last one: any idea how to clear all the underline all in once? (The text need to be edited or reopen to remove it)

Comment: got it, add Application.ScreenRefresh to the end of macro (will edit now)

Comment: Yes it works, I updated your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I like your timed button, but don't really want to put it in the answer as it is too broad to answer the original question. Can find it in the edit history if anyone is interested

Comment: yes I agree, I was just to exited about it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

So I have it set up a little differently. I mainly use it when I am writing out presentations that have code in it. I've assigned the macros to keys and here are both macros:

This will ignore all proofing, so gets rid of those annoying markers from Word

```
    Sub CodeFont()
'
' CodeFont Macro
' Change font to differentiate code
'
    Selection.Font.Name = "Consolas"
    Selection.Font.Size = 11
    Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
    Selection.NoProofing = True
End Sub
```

And when I want to revert back to "normal" typing

```
Sub Normal()
'
' Normal Macro
'
'
    Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    Selection.Font.Size = 12
    Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
    Selection.NoProofing = False
End Sub
```